# What is the problem with passing a char into a function with parameter of char

Tags: c++

```
char word1;
int compute_score(char word);

int main(void)
{
    cin >> word1;
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
}

int compute_score(char word)
{
 // this function then will compute the size of word1
}
```

Error Message: argument of type char is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Comment: strlen of char?

Comment: @S.M. Oops, I was so focused on `compute_score` I missed that. Apologies to johann

Comment: `strlen` is a function which takes a pointer to char, not a char, so this is an error `strlen(word)`. Hard to know what to suggest as a fix however without more context. In any case you should realise that `char` means a single char, not a string.

Comment: In C, `char` means one character (not a word, not a string).

Comment: Probably you need to change `word1` to be an array of char, and then make other changes in the rest of your code. But only guessing.

Comment: I think that might be the problem, I am simply looking to get the size of the char. I guess I would have to use sizeof(charname). And then convert from bytes to get the number of words in the char?

Comment: @johanndewey A char is a **single** character, always. Seems that you want an **array** of char.

Comment: if my char is a word, then its a char array correct? If the word is "book", how would I get the size of the char so that I get an integer of 4?

Comment: A char is a **single** char always, Your char cannot be a word, it's impossible.

Comment: A std::string would then be in order.

Comment: How about showing the code that makes you think that your char variable is a word? That might be where you real error is.

Comment: okay let me edit the post

Comment: This code `cin >> word1;` reads a single char. If you want proof, try this code `cin >> word1; cout << word1 << endl;` and see what happens.

Comment: That makes sense, okay I'm going to try to find out how to get user input and store it into an array of chars. I think thats what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yes, seems reasonable. But the better alternative would be to use `std::string`. That the C++ solution, using arrays of char is what a C programmer would do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the easiest way for what you are trying to do.

```
# include <iostream>

std::string word1;
int compute_score(std::string word);

int main(void)
{
    std::cin >> word1;
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    std::cout << score1;
}

int compute_score(std::string word)
{
     return word.length();
}
```